# python 3 float sum

Tags: python, floating-point, sum

- 0.15
- 0.98
- 0.92

I've got float numbers which comes from mongodb as above and try to sum of the numbers with code below and getting error.

```
for document in cursor:
    Price = (document['Price'])
    item = (datetime.strptime(cortime(document['TimeStamp']), "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"))
    dif = str(li - item)
        if dif  <= '0:05:00':
           try:
                        print(sum(Price))
           except Exception as error:
                        print(error)
```

Error: 
     `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: A number of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unsupported+operand+type%28s%29+for+%2B%3A+%27int%27+and+%27str%27) posts about unsupported operand type(s) may be helpful to you

Comment: Also be very very careful when comparing strings, since they are compared lexicographically (character by character: `"20"` is, indeed less than `"3"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document['Price']` apparently contains a mixture of strings and numbers. You should convert all the elements to numbers first.

```
Price = [float(x) for x in document['Price']]
```